# Lodash flow-typed filter or pickBy with multiple types

Tags: filter, lodash, flow-typed

Using `pickBy` or `filter` in lodash 4x using flow-typed, my input object has numbers and strings. So I'm getting the error "Cannot call pickBy because number [1] is incompatible with string [2]"

Trying to do

```
const inputWithoutEmptyFields = pickBy(input, (v) => v !== undefined)
```

Comment: What is the input? What is the desired output?

Comment: Input is a hash of keys and values. All are strings except one is an Integer. Desired output is the same hash with any key/value that has a null value removed from the hash.

Comment: Add sample input and expected output.